# Create a Task with an Action<T>

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I somehow feel I am missing something basic. Here's my problem.

I am trying to create a System.Threading.Tasks.Task instance to execute an action that accepts a parameter of a certain type. I thought I could do something like

```
void DoWork(MyClass obj) {} //My action that accepts a parameter of type 'MyClass'

MyClass obj = new MyClass(); 
Action<MyClass> action = DoWork; //action that points to the method
Task task = new Task(action,obj); //task that would execute 'DoWork' with 'obj' as the parameter when I call Start.
```

Obviously this does not compile. It seems I can only use an `Action<object>` and not an `Action<T>` for a task and then cast the 'object' to T inside my method.

How can I achieve what I want most effectively and efficiently?

Answer (score 10):

You also can use directly:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
Task task = Task.Run(() => DoWork(obj));
```

Comment: Just to mention: This has a slightly different meaning. If you change the *variable* `obj` before starting the task, or even just before the `Task` logic called the delegate, `DoWork` will work on the new object. This can lead to bugs which are very hard to track. A classic situation would be, if you use this inside a loop `foreach(MyClass o in myObjList) { (new Task(()=>DoWork(o))).Start(); }`.

Comment: @MartinStettner, _"A classic situation would be, if you use this inside a loop"_ foreach loop has been changed and now such code is correct.

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```
Action<Object> action = o => DoWork((MyClass)o);
Task task = new Task(action, obj);
```

---

<s>If you're using .NET 4.0 or above, you can use [Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to achieve your goal without introducing a new delegate</s>

```
//INCORRECT Code, casts InvalidCastException at runtime
Action action = DoWork;
Task task = new Task((Action)action, obj);
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for @svick for pointing out, that the second option is not correct: I was too busy sorting out, whether Action is co- or contravariant (it is in fact contravariant, I was right about this at least) that I oversaw, that I would need *Covariance* in this case.

Contravariance means that you can do

```
Action<object> action1 = someAction;
Action<SubClass> action2 = action1;
```

without explicit casting.

Comment: Any reason why this is not part of the API?

Comment: `Task` is in the framework since .Net 4.0, so I think that qualifier is not necessary.

Comment: Also, that's not how contravariance works, you can cast `Action<object>` to `Action<MyClass>`, but not the other way around.